# Remove box from Firemonkey Text3d

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

### ** This is **fixed** in Delphi XE2 Update 3 **

I've create a little Hello World Firemonkey application with a spinning tText3d object.
How do I get rid of the wireframe box that surrounds the text?

**Edit:** This is a screenshot of a `TText3D` object with `Text` value 'hullo!' on a Viewport3D in a FireMonkey HD form.  A `TTimer` changes one of the rotation values every so often.  It rotates, but looks like this:

[image: Strange TText3D bug]

The size of the wireframe changes when you change the caption, so maybe that's where the text is supposed to be.  No idea what the black bars are.

[image: It takes some fiddling to get the text into the box. Now I want to get rid of the box.]

---

I'm looking at the source code for tText3D . Render. 
The last lines say, more or less,

If in design mode then
draw a box.

Except, the IF part is commented out, so that the box is always drawn whether in design mode or not.

Comment: My first reaction was 'What? Surely there's no wireframe.' Then I tried it. It's all very strange.  I edited the question to include my screenshot, attempting to reproduce from the OP's description - @user1008646, please feel free to remove this or change it to a screenshot of your own form.

Comment: I wanted to add a screen shot, but I didn't know you could do that here.  How do add a graphic to your question?

Comment: In the toolbar above the text field is an image button (I think it's the sixth from the left, next to the braces {} code button.) When you click it you can upload an image from your computer.

Comment: is it possible to get screenshot of a direct3d renderd image

Comment: I took the above screenshot with Windows 7's Snipping Tool, so it must be.  I don't know if Snagit or other tools will handle it.

Comment: It appears there's no way to turn it off after all.  I looked at the source for tText3D . Render, hoping to find something that says "If the draw-a-box property is set, then draw a box". What I found instead was: "If in design mode, then draw a box", except that the IF part is commented out, so it always draws the box.

Comment: In that case, [file a bug with Embarcadero's QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx), and it will hopefully be patched.  In the meantime, try deriving a custom component from `TText3D` and override the `Render` method.